# Bootstrap Row won't center columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a 3 column layout, which turns into 2 or 1 columns on smaller screens. I'm using React to populate many columns inside a row, but everything combined is something like this:

```
    <Grid className="property-grid">
       <Row className="property-row">
          <Col xs={12} md={4} className="property-thumbnail" key={this.props.key}>
              <div className="thumbnail">
                <Image src={this.props.img} responsive className="property-pic" />
              </div>
              <div className="property-padded">
                <p>some description</p>
              </div>
          </Col>
          .
          .
          /* other columns */
          .
          .
       </Row>
    </Grid>
```

Here's how it looks[image]

```
.properties-grid {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.properties-row {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.property-thumbnail {
  margin: 2em auto;
  background-color: green;
  display: table-cell;
  max-width: 450px;
}
```

I want the last odd column row to be on the left, so I tried using `display: inline-block`. But then this happens [image]

How do I make the first row look like the first picture (centered columns and some gap between them) while making sure last row stay on the left?

Comment: Why us this tagged Bootstrap? You don't appear to be using Bootstrap class at all.

Comment: I'm using react-bootstrap which is basically a wrapper around Bootstrap 3, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Yes, but still the `.properties-grid`, and `.properties-row` are completely custom so it's not a "Bootstrap row".

Comment: I simply gave them names and customized in an attempt to center the columns. You can assume it's `<div class="row" id="properties-row">` and `<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="property-thumbnail">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `margin:2em auto;` from your class `.property-thumbnail`

> It pushes your contents in your class `.property-thumbnail` to come in the center, if there are less than **3 elements**  in your `property-row`

```js
const Grid = ReactBootstrap.Grid;
const Row = ReactBootstrap.Row;
const Col = ReactBootstrap.Col;
const Panel = ReactBootstrap.Panel;
const ButtonToolbar = ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar;
const Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
const Form = ReactBootstrap.Form;
const Image = ReactBootstrap.Image;
const Test = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return ( <
      Grid className = "property-grid" >
      <
      Row className = "property-row" >
      <
      Col xs = {
        12
      }
      md = {
        4
      }
      className = "property-thumbnail"
      key = {
        this.props.key
      } >
      <
      div className = "thumbnail" >
      <
      Image src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg"
      responsive className = "property-pic" / >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = "property-padded" >
      <
      p > some description < /p> <
      /div> <
      /Col> <
      Col xs = {
        12
      }
      md = {
        4
      }
      className = "property-thumbnail"
      key = {
        this.props.key
      } >
      <
      div className = "thumbnail" >
      <
      Image src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg"
      responsive className = "property-pic" / >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = "property-padded" >
      <
      p > some description < /p> <
      /div> <
      /Col> <
      Col xs = {
        12
      }
      md = {
        4
      }
      className = "property-thumbnail"
      key = {
        this.props.key
      } >
      <
      div className = "thumbnail" >
      <
      Image src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg"
      responsive className = "property-pic" / >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = "property-padded" >
      <
      p > some description < /p> <
      /div> <
      /Col> <
      Col xs = {
        12
      }
      md = {
        4
      }
      className = "property-thumbnail"
      key = {
        this.props.key
      } >
      <
      div className = "thumbnail" >
      <
      Image src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg"
      responsive className = "property-pic" / >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = "property-padded" >
      <
      p > some description < /p> <
      /div> <
      /Col> <
      Col xs = {
        12
      }
      md = {
        4
      }
      className = "property-thumbnail"
      key = {
        this.props.key
      } >
      <
      div className = "thumbnail" >
      <
      Image src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg"
      responsive className = "property-pic" / >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = "property-padded" >
      <
      p > some description < /p> <
      /div> <
      /Col> <
      /Row> <
      /Grid>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( < Test / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.property-grid {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.property-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.property-thumbnail {
  background-color: green;
  display: table-cell;
  max-width: 450px;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .property-thumbnail {
    margin: 2em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.29.4/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Have added media-query which will be useful in your case.

> Please adjust `max-width` in the query. (Though I will do it soon, will be travelling for 24 hrs)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Bootstrap grid the way it's supposed to be used, it would layout like you want.

https://www.codeply.com/go/0pJfjcpGgK

```
<div class="container properties-grid">
    <div class="row properties-row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 property-thumbnail">
            <img src="//placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 property-thumbnail">
            <img src="//placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 property-thumbnail">
            <img src="//placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 property-thumbnail">
            <img src="//placehold.it/300x200" class="thumbnail center-block">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```